# How to download new version of file without using the client cache?

Tags: javascript, html, browser-cache

I have page where I have table with users data and each row (each user has their own business card which is a tag that reference to pdf that is stored on server.

```
   <td class="business_card">
    <a href="/static/users_documents/9/business_card.pdf" target="_blank">
    <img src="/static/images/business_card.png" name="business_card" alt="business_card_image">
    </a>
   </td>
```

When user send post request, previously pdf file on server is deleted and new pdf is created.
But, problem is that browser cache old version of file, and I must press every time `CTRL+F5` to hard refresh cache and then I can see file from server, not from cache.

Do I need to use JavaScript to clear cache?
Also, my a tag reference to page like this:

```
https://192.168.2.244/static/users_documents/9/business_card.pdf
```

and html for that page is created by Firefox to display my pdf file.

Some additional info which may help is that I'm using Nginx server on Ubuntu 16.04.3.

Comment: Just add unique query to URL, e.g. using timestamp: `url + '?' + Date.now()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To expand on what @hindmost is saying in the comments, a browser will not use a cached version of the document if the URL has a query attached to it, with a number that is higher than a previously cached version of this file. Usually this will be done by adding `?v=2` or something like that to the url. Using `Date.now()` ensures this number is always higher than any previously cached version.

`url + '?v=' + Date.now();` will result in a unique version number every time, and since time only counts forward, the number will always be larger than the previous version.

Answer (score 6):

You could also fix this by using the HTTP header `Cache-Control` on the server.

Using `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate` would tell the browser not to cache the URL and to always request a new file.

On the plus side, since it doesn't use JavaScript, this would also work on browsers with JavaScript disabled.

Source: [Cache-Control on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control)